# Pattern match a polymorphic type in a concrete type in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm using elm-form: https://github.com/etaque/elm-form/, and I need to pattern match a polymorphic type into a concrete type, however I got the next error:

```
The pattern matches things of type:

    TranslationId

But the values it will actually be trying to match are:

    e

Hint: Your type annotation uses type variable `e` which means any type of value
can flow through. Your code is saying it CANNOT be anything though! Maybe change
your type annotation to be more specific? Maybe the code has a problem? More at:
<https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/type-annotations.md>
```

The code in question is this:

```
translateError : ErrorValue e -> String
translateError error =
    case error of
        InvalidEmail ->
            translate English ErrInvalidEmail

        Empty ->
            translate English ErrEmpty

        CustomError PasswordNotMatch ->
            translate English PasswordNotMatch

        x ->
            toString x
```

ErrorValue type https://github.com/etaque/elm-form/blob/f9480cb8646ebc9f78f13d3a7482c463c5275776/src/Form/Error.elm#L19:

```
type ErrorValue e
    = Empty
    | InvalidString
    | InvalidEmail
    | InvalidUrl
    | InvalidFormat
    | InvalidInt
    | InvalidFloat
    | InvalidBool
    | InvalidDate
    | SmallerIntThan Int
    | GreaterIntThan Int
    | SmallerFloatThan Float
    | GreaterFloatThan Float
    | ShorterStringThan Int
    | LongerStringThan Int
    | NotIncludedIn
    | CustomError e
```

TranslationId type https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/Translations/Utils.elm#L9:

```
type TranslationId
    = ErrInvalidEmail
    | PasswordNotMatch
    | ErrEmpty
```

I came up with a solution, but it looks weird and I'm not sure if it's the right one https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/Translations/FormErrors.elm#L7:

```
translateError : ErrorValue e -> String
translateError error =
    case error of
        InvalidEmail ->
            translate English ErrInvalidEmail

        Empty ->
            translate English ErrEmpty

        CustomError e ->
            case (toString e) of
                "PasswordNotMatch" ->
                    translate English PasswordNotMatch
                x ->
                    toString x

        x ->
            toString x
```

Comment: That's because you're not specifying what `e` is in `translateError : ErrorValue e -> String` - so it doesn't know anything about it. Maybe pass in the `e -> String` function?

Answer (score 2):

As @reactormonk says, you are not addressing the type variable in your type definition. elm-form provides flexibility in the custom error through this type variable, which you have to supply yourself if you want to use custom errors (if you do not then you can use the variable throughout your code with no problem).

In particular `ErrorValue` has a type variable `e` that you need to specify: it does not matter in the code that does not use the CustomError constructor, but does matter in `translateError` because you are trying to pattern match on CustomError. It looks as though the type you want is `TranslationId` so you want

```
translateError : ErrorValue TranslationId -> String
translateError error =
    case error of
        InvalidEmail ->
            translate English ErrInvalidEmail

        Empty ->
            translate English ErrEmpty

        CustomError PasswordNotMatch ->
            translate English PasswordNotMatch

        x ->
            toString x
```

Comment: I did that, then I call it from [here](https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/ViewHelpers.elm#L32), then I changed the type signature by: `errorFor : FieldState TranslationId String -> Html msg`, then I got an error from [here](https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/ViewHelpers.elm#L25), finally I got stuck.

Comment: I tried make my answer a little more complete, but the advice is the same

Comment: Yes, I appreciate you took the time to checked this out. However, maybe I didn't explain enough, following your advice I get to this [point](https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/ViewHelpers.elm#L25), which calls a function `getFieldAsString` from elm-form package, as you can see [here](https://github.com/etaque/elm-form/blob/3e97913dab84f2fb5432379664a9f578d4158f48/src/Form.elm#L92), it expects a type of the form: `FieldState e String`, however I'm passing: `FieldState TranslationId String`, this generates the error.

Comment: I could fork the package and change the type signature of `getFieldAsString`, but I was thinking that maybe there is a better solution, thanks for all the help.

Comment: The error you are getting is in your code, not in elm-form. Your error is https://github.com/werner/madison-elm/blob/master/src/elm/Translations/FormErrors.elm#L7 and is because you are trying to pattern match on type `CustomError e` without having specified what type `e` is